# odoo move VAT to another page

Tags: xml, inheritance, odoo-8, formview

Hello I'd like to move the "VAT" field on the res.partner form from the 'Accounting' tab to the upper part of the form, where the address, etc is listed.

I tried doing so by

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="res_partner_vat_form_inherit">
        <field name="name">res.partner.vat.form.inherit</field>
        <field name="model">res.partner</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="vat" position="replace"/>
            <field name="website" position="after">
                <field name="vat"/>
            </field>
        </field>
    </record>
```

But this gave me the error that field name="vat" couldn't be located in parent view. This is because the page 'Accounting' is added by another inherited view (account.view_partner_property_form). 
I'm thinking of inheriting on this view but don't really know how to combine the above code and the inheritance on the account.view_partner_property_form.

Comment: I'd like to change this too, did you finally solve it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="res_partner_vat_form_inherit">
        <field name="name">res.partner.vat.form.inherit</field>
        <field name="model">res.partner</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">

            <field name="website" position="after">
                <field name="vat"/>
            </field>
        </field>
    </record>
```

This will help you to swap the information given inside a form view using a button